# Jdk8 debug without libjsig.debuginfo

Tags: makefile, cmake, java-8

When building JDK 8 with parameters:
--with-milestone=fcs
--with-update-version=152
--with-user-release-suffix=
--with-build-number=b16
--disable-zip-debug-info
--disable-precompiled-headers
--with-debug-level=slowdebug
--with-jvm-variants=zerosnark

An error appears during build:

```
## Starting hotspot
...
**NOTICE** Dtrace support disabled: /usr/include/sys/sdt.h not found
All done.
INFO: ENABLE_FULL_DEBUG_SYMBOLS=1 
INFO: ALT_OBJCOPY=/usr/bin/objcopy 
INFO: /usr/bin/objcopy cmd found so will create .debuginfo files. 
INFO: STRIP_POLICY=min_strip 
INFO: ZIP_DEBUGINFO_FILES=0
INFO: ENABLE_FULL_DEBUG_SYMBOLS=1
INFO: ALT_OBJCOPY=/usr/bin/objcopy
INFO: /usr/bin/objcopy cmd found so will create .debuginfo files.
INFO: STRIP_POLICY=min_strip
INFO: ZIP_DEBUGINFO_FILES=0
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '/ .../build/linux-x86_64-normal-zeroshark-slowdebug/hotspot/dist/jre/lib/amd64/libjsig.debuginfo', needed by 'generic_export'. Stop.  
make[2]: *** [Makefile: 321: export_debug] Error 2 
make[1]: *** [HotspotWrapper.gmk: 48: .../build/linux-x86_64-normal-zeroshark-slowdebug/hotspot/_hotspot.timestamp] Error 2 make: *** [...//make/Main.gmk:117: hotspot-only] Error 2
```

Collect is obtained through:

```
make ENABLE_FULL_DEBUG_SYMBOLS=0
```

Or if you copy

> linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/dist/jre/lib/amd64/libjsig.debuginfo

to

> linux-x86_64-normal-zeroshark-slowdebug/hotspot/dist/jre/lib/amd64/

I looked through a lot of .make/.gmk files and couldn't find the error.
The question is, how much will the absence of libjsig. debuginfo affect the debug mode? What is libjsig.debuginfo responsible for?

Comment: Your quoted content has a lot of whitespace errors in it.  Whitespace is critically important so you need to be sure when you copy/paste that it's preserved exactly.  For example, there's no way that you run `make ENABLE_FULL_DEBUG_SYMBOLS = 0` and it works.  You have to have run `make ENABLE_FULL_DEBUG_SYMBOLS=0`.  Does your error output also contain extra spaces that aren't in the real output?  Your error messages show `libjsig.debuginfo '` with a trailing space: is that space really there?  Or is it just another error in your cut and paste of the message?

Comment: @MadScientist 
I apologize. There are no spaces in the report, this is a copying error.